# Broken Display After Installing Kubuntu on Older Mac Pro

Tags: installation, kubuntu, mac

I downloaded the Kubunutu 13.10 64-bit installer and made a bootable USB stick.

I want to install Kubuntu on a fresh partition on my Mac Pro 1,1 which is currently running Xubuntu 13.10 (as well as Mac OS X). I had to do the install by booting the installer on my newer Macbook, since the Mac Pro will not boot Ubuntu disks or USB sticks (something about EFI or some such).

So I booted the installer on the Macbook, and installed into the new partition on Mac Pro via Firewire Target Disk mode. The install succeeded, and I am able to boot into Kubuntu on Mac Pro. But the display is wonky, perhaps because it was installed from a different machine with a different monitor(?).

The login screen looks fine, and some of the "desktop" (forgive my terminology; I'm new to KDE) such as the "Desktop" button in the upper right corner of the screen is OK. But the panel along the bottom of the screen is completely trashed, as are any menus and popups. I can hack around and launch Konsole and Dolphin and they display normally, but parts of the windows get blanked out randomly.

I managed to launch bin/systemsettings and looked at the Display and Monitors setting. It shows the proper display resolution.

How can I straighten this problem out?

EDIT:

I just tried Plan B, installing the kubuntu-full package into my working Xubuntu partition. Kubuntu has the same display problems. Xubuntu continues to work fine.

Comment: It might be an issue of a graphic driver, could you paste here output of `sudo lshw -c video`?

Comment: @Tombart:`$ sudo lshw -c video
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: G73 [GeForce 7300 GT]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
       resources: irq:16 memory:f1000000-f1ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f0ffffff ioport:1000(size=128) memory:f2000000-f201ffff`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem might be in using proprietary NVidia drivers, there are few ways how to solve it:

1. Use the recommended way of installation. Check the Mac Pro documentation page:

   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacPro

   (or MacBook Pro apporoach might be also helpful: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro)
2. Install Linux with the old school way from DVD, which installs grub-pc and boots Linux in BIOS compatibility mode (without (U)EFI)
3. Use alternative drivers (might depend on specific (k)ubuntu version and MacPro version)